# Paypal checkout solution for react-native to connect with rest paypal API

Tags: react-native, paypal, payment, braintree

I am using react native with an Rest Paypal API already implemented in my Meteor Backend. So is there any package or way to do something like express checkout for react native? for example if I use braintree as paypal payment solution can it connect with my Rest Paypal API ?

Comment: get  any solution?

Comment: no at the moment i just use in app browser to do it it work but is not perfect

Comment: or any other payment gateway working in React native?

Comment: you could try stripe

Comment: which module of stripe working perfct? can you help to find this?

Comment: I am sorry I don't know that as well